# How to I use the cmake command protobuf_generate when installing protobuf through FetchContent?

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-c++

I am writing a client/server with gRPC. To generate the client/server protobuf code, I need to run the cmake command `protobuf_generate`. If I install protobuf beforehand, I have access to the command `protobuf_generate`. However, if I try to install protobuf with `FetchContent`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(ProtoObjects)

include(FetchContent)
set(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET OFF)
FetchContent_Declare(
  gRPC
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/grpc/grpc
  GIT_TAG        v1.49.2
  )
FetchContent_Declare(
    Protobuf
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf
    GIT_TAG        v21.12 
    SOURCE_SUBDIR  cmake
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(gRPC Protobuf)

add_library(
    proto-objects
        PUBLIC
            grpc++
)

target_include_directories(proto-objects PUBLIC "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROTO_GENERATED_DIR}>")

protobuf_generate(
    TARGET proto-objects
    IMPORT_DIRS ${PROTO_IMPORT_DIRS}
    PROTOC_OUT_DIR ${PROTO_GENERATED_DIR}
)

protobuf_generate(
    TARGET proto-objects
    LANGUAGE grpc
    GENERATE_EXTENSIONS .grpc.pb.h .grpc.pb.cc
    PLUGIN "protoc-gen-grpc=\$<TARGET_FILE:gRPC::grpc_cpp_plugin>"
    IMPORT_DIRS ${PROTO_IMPORT_DIRS}
    PROTOC_OUT_DIR "${PROTO_GENERATED_DIR}"
)
```

I get the error:

```
Unknown CMake command "protobuf_generate".
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: `SOURCE_SUBDIR  cmake` - This usage of Protobuf is deprecated, and CMake emits [warning](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/v21.12/cmake/CMakeLists.txt#L3) about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Protobuf version 21.12 and before the function `protobuf_generate` is defined in the [protobuf-config.cmake](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/v21.12/cmake/protobuf-config.cmake.in) script which is created upon installation. Thus the function can be used only with already installed Protobuf, but not with the one included with FetchContent.

In the master (after [that pull request](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/pull/10426)) the function `protobuf_generate` is defined in the script [cmake/protobuf-generate.cmake](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/ad55f52fdb4557953593cd096b903b0347b02f25/cmake/protobuf-generate.cmake), so that script can be included even in the build tree (after FetchContent):

```
...
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(Protobuf)

# Get source directory of the Protobuf
FetchContent_GetProperties(Protobuf SOURCE_DIR Protobuf_SOURCE_DIR)
# Include the script which defines 'protobuf_generate'
include(${Protobuf_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/protobuf-generate.cmake)

...
protobuf_generate(...)
```

Comment: Thanks, I couldnt actually get this to work in the end because I couldnt get it to install the dependencies (asbl), however adding grpc as a submodule worked for me so I am doing it that way for now. I will accept the answer anyway :)

Comment: I couldn't get this to work either.

Comment: @McFlurriez: What exact part doesn't work for you and which error message you got? Just checked the Protobuf repo, it still has the file [cmake/protobuf-generate.cmake](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/cmake/protobuf-generate.cmake) and that file still defines the function `protobuf_generate`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I'm getting this error:

CMake Error: install(EXPORT "myprojectTargets" ...) includes target "myproject" which requires target "proto-objects" that is not in any export set. In this case "proto-objects" is the library created to hold the protobuf compiled objects:

add_library(proto-objects OBJECT ${PROTO_SRC}).

I've tried a lot of fiddling/searching to make it work but I've got nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I use fetch content to get/compile grpc and then also use it to generate my protos.

I hope this helps -- this cmake file lives in ./protos in my project and is called via `add_subdirectory(protos)` in my main CMakeLists.txt file.

```
project(your-project)

# example from: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/cmake/common.cmake

# setting vars used in the custom command
set(_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF protobuf::libprotobuf)
set(_PROTOBUF_PROTOC $<TARGET_FILE:protobuf::protoc>)
set(_GRPC_GRPCPP grpc++)
set(_REFLECTION grpc++_reflection)
set(_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE $<TARGET_FILE:grpc_cpp_plugin>)

# Proto file for real-time gtfs
get_filename_component(rt_gtfs_proto "gtfs_realtime.proto" ABSOLUTE)
get_filename_component(rt_gtfs_proto_path "${rt_gtfs_proto}" PATH)

# Generated sources
set(rt_gtfs_proto_srcs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gtfs_realtime.pb.cc")
set(rt_gtfs_proto_hdrs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gtfs_realtime.pb.h")

get_filename_component(DIR_ONE_ABOVE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../ ABSOLUTE)


# compile real-time gtfs protos
add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT "${rt_gtfs_proto_srcs}" "${rt_gtfs_proto_hdrs}"
        COMMAND ${_PROTOBUF_PROTOC}
        ARGS --cpp_out "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
        -I "${rt_gtfs_proto_path}" "${rt_gtfs_proto}"
        DEPENDS "${rt_gtfs_proto}")

# Include generated *.pb.h files
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")

# rg_grpc_proto
add_library(tp_grpc_proto
        ${rt_gtfs_proto_srcs}
        ${rt_gtfs_proto_hdrs})

target_link_libraries(tp_grpc_proto
        ${_REFLECTION}
        ${_GRPC_GRPCPP}
        ${_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF})
```