# Is there a way to generate grpc files using cmake and FetchContent?

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a project with a cmake file at the root which fetches gRPC using FetchContent.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(my-project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# gRPC
FetchContent_Declare(
        gRPC
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/grpc/grpc
        GIT_TAG master
)
set(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET OFF)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(gRPC)
```

I now need to generate C++ files using my `.proto` files in `./protos`. However, every example I've seen uses some form of

```
find_package(protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

which requires protobuf and gRPC to be installed prior to build.

Here is an example of a project with that structure:

https://github.com/faaxm/exmpl-cmake-grpc

Is there a way to use FetchContent, and also tell CMake to generate the gRPC server files?

I want to do something like this:

```
set(PROTO_FILES
        protos/myservice.proto)

# protobuf source files go into the lib just like any other CPP source file
add_library(my-service ${PROTO_FILES})
target_link_libraries(my-service
        PUBLIC
        protobuf::libprotobuf
        gRPC::grpc
        gRPC::grpc++
        )

target_include_directories(my-service
        PUBLIC
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
get_target_property(grpc_cpp_plugin_location gRPC::grpc_cpp_plugin LOCATION)

protobuf_generate(server.cc my-service LANGUAGE cpp)

# compile the GRPC services
protobuf_generate(
        TARGET
        my-service
        LANGUAGE
        grpc
        GENERATE_EXTENSIONS
        .grpc.pb.h
        .grpc.pb.cc
        PLUGIN
        "protoc-gen-grpc=${grpc_cpp_plugin_location}"
)
```

But because I'm not using `find_package` the `protobuf_generate()` function is not defined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74844369/how-to-i-use-the-cmake-command-protobuf-generate-when-installing-protobuf-throug

Comment: No, it didn't. The solution originally posted there didn't answer that OP's question either, it just gives  a workaround. I posted the full solution to my question, and to OP's question over there. The difference is that there is actually a way to use FetchContent's version of protobuf that is installed through grpc, instead of having to manually install protobuf and use that version.